# VB.NET OleDb Connection.Close()/.Dispose() takes too long to execute

Tags: database, vb.net, connection, database-connection, oledb

OleDb connection.close() takes >40s each to execute, when doing quite a few in one go it takes 3 minutes to complete everything. No clue what to do, nobody on the internet seems to have a solution. On extremely rare occasions it executes normally and at a speed I would expect, I wouldn't know how to reproduce this, though.

The actual database itself is fine and doesn't take too long to load in Access

```
Public Sub loadCoords(orderstoset As List(Of Order))

    For Each order In orderstoset

        Dim query As String = "SELECT Address FROM Clients WHERE ClientID = '" & order.getID & "';"
        Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
        Dim myDataReader As OleDbDataReader
        myConnection.ConnectionString =
            "provider=Microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;Data Source = C:\Users\jackw\OneDrive\Access Database\WaggyTailzDatabase.accdb"

        Try

            myConnection.Open()
            Dim myCommand As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, myConnection)
            myDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader

            While myDataReader.Read

                Dim coords As String
                Dim myOrder As New Order
                Dim address As String = myDataReader("Address").ToString
                coords = addressToLatLon(address)
                order.setCoords(coords)
                i += 1

            End While

        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox(ex.Message)

        End Try

        myConnection.Close()

    Next

End Sub
```

Also tried .Dispose(), same thing. No error messages or anything, just takes a long time which is very annoying considering the amount of times I do it. This is not the only section this happens, got a few more and they all do the same thing. 
Thanks for any help

Comment: Does it help if you myDataReader.Close() when you are done with it? Also, try [Using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader?view=netframework-4.8). The Close should be really fast, you have a weird problem.

Comment: ^ Using is a must. You are creating a new connection,reader, command per iteration. You should only need 1 connection and per iteration use consume and destroy the reader/command, once the iteration is complete close and destroy the connection.